# cocreateinsatnce returns the system cannot find the file specified in COM

Tags: com

```
 CoInitialize(NULL);
GCalender::IGCalenderSync* pGCalender;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(GCalender::GCalenderSyncHelper),NULL, 
   CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,__uuidof(GCalender::IGCalenderSync),(void**)&pGCalender);

GCalender::GenericEvent HUGEP *pDeletedEvents;  
GCalender::GenericEvent HUGEP *pUpdatedEvents;  
GCalender::GenericEvent HUGEP *pNewEvents;  

SAFEARRAY* deletedEvents, *updatedEvents, *newEvents;
pGCalender->GetAllEvents(&deletedEvents, &updatedEvents, &newEvents);

hr = SafeArrayAccessData(newEvents, (void HUGEP* FAR*)&pNewEvents);
SafeArrayUnaccessData(newEvents);
hr = SafeArrayAccessData(deletedEvents, (void HUGEP* FAR*)&pDeletedEvents);
SafeArrayUnaccessData(deletedEvents);
hr = SafeArrayAccessData(updatedEvents, (void HUGEP* FAR*)&pUpdatedEvents);
SafeArrayUnaccessData(updatedEvents);
CoUninitialize();
```

in the above code the HR value is 0X8007002 ( system cannot find the file specified)
How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

That happens if the COM server for the class id you passed into `CoCreateInstance()` is registered, but for whatever reason the .dll file or one of its dependencies can't be found. Your best bet is [Process Monitor utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) - it will let you see what file exactly is missing.

Comment: I created the sample with above its working.. But when i integrate it into the COM DLL project. its not working.. FYI.. if i change the context to CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER to CLSCTX_ALL . cocreateinstance will returns the "class not registered".

Comment: @Mahantesh: Process Monitor will be more helpful that trying to guess.